# How to define minimum height for tbody in CSS

Tags: css, css-tables

I want to set a minimum height for tbody in CSS, even if no `<tr><td></td></tr>` in tbody, here is my code:

```css
tbody{
  height: 500px;
  min-height:500px;
}
```

but it doesn't work. so what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Show some more code so we understand exactly what you are hoping to achieve. It may be that a table is not the right choice of markup for what you want to do.

Comment: Probably you need to add a `width` too if there is no content...

Comment: remove height: 500px;

Comment: I have the same problem. My table has filter on each column. When only few records are displayed, I want the table footer stay at the bottom still rather than jump up and down. If I set `tbody` display to 'block', then the column with does not align with thead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why you want to do this?

Min-height and height applies to block level elements and table isn't a block level element.
Wrap your table inside a div (say div.table-wrap) and apply minimum height to that div.

If you don't want table layout isn't important to you, then just add `display:block` to the CSS of tbody.

Comment: sorry, I don't know min-height can't applied to tbody element. I  want `tbody` to leave some space away from `thead` if no content in `tbody`,and I just try to add `display:block`, this makes the table look very ugly. Maybe I should use `div` element instead. Thanks.

Comment: A table can have more than one <tbody>.  I'd like them to be a min-height.

Comment: Answering question with a question is not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this demo will work for you...

Css:

```
  tbody{
     height: auto;
     min-height:200px;
     display:block
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/kW5ek/)

Answer (score 2):

We needed the min-height on the `<tbody>` as we could not inject other HTML elements (user content). I found a fix.

Height works for an empty table, but not if the empty table has an empty tbody in Chrome (59) - it works for Firefox and Egde. Also other cases hidden `<tr>` gave issues, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nbq6duf/) for all cases.

CSS:

```
.test {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Html:

```
Empty table:
<table class=test>

</table>

Empty tbody:
<table class=test>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Chrome 59:

[image: Chrome 59]

Edge (14), IE (11), Firefox (54):

[image]

Fixed this with:

```
tbody:before {
  content: ''/* needed for chrome*/
}
```

See [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz0Lzqah/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do,

```
table{height:500px !important;}
```

now this `!important` will make it voluntary, it will be overridden easily by other attributes.

tbody does not carry the height property.

it carries only 4 properties 'align', 'char','charoff' & 'valign' as per standardization of CSS.

also this will work with cell of same size and cell spacing added in remaining space.

```
tbody{
  height:500px;
  display:block; 
}
```

Try and reply, I hope this will do :)

Comment: the min-height will be completely ignored by the tbody tag

Comment: Yes will not support, I referred the code again and revised it too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following instead as tbody can't have min-height but still works height for datatable

```
tbody{
    height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add display: block; too.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you're using IE 5 or 6. Why not only use height instead? Try removing min-height because there is  no point in setting height and min-height on the same element because all you will get is a fixed height and not min-height at all.

Comment: you can add `height:80%; min-height:400px;`. Your answer doesn't help the question.