# Make tbody fixed height

Tags: css

I have a table with filter on every column. When filter matches few records, my tfoot contents will jump up and down. So I want to set the tbody height to fixed value to let tfoot stay at the bottom.

I have seen similar questions like [how to define minimum height for tbody in css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15519249/2197555),

but it does not solve my problem.

Setting height of wrapper div does not solve this. Setting tbody 'display: block' will make the columns width not aligned with thead any more.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`table { table-layout: fixed; }` To control the height place divs inside of tds and adjust the height of the divs

This [article](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/) is very comprehensive

```js
var mid = document.querySelector('.center');
var up = document.getElementById('up');

up.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  mid.style.height = "200px";
}, false);
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 90%;
}
th {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button id="up">UP</button>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div></div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="center"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out how this can work. The problem is tbody is populated dynamically. There may be no tr at all if filter matches none record. Or should I just use javascript to forcefully insert blank row in tbody?

Comment: @gm2008 I don't think `tbody` is the element to be concerned with, tables are content oriented. `tbody` never touches content. Take a look at my demo, you'll see that the content in the middle cell increase in height and the table will adjust to it.

Comment: *Or should I just use javascript to forcefully insert blank row in tbody?* If you get dynamically generated tables, CSS will still affect it . I have to deal with those crappy tables as well and I use 80% CSS and 20% JS/jQ.